# Why do PHP for loops allow a list of guard expressions?

Tags: php, for-loop

A PHP `for`-loop [is defined like so](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php):

```
for (expr1; expr2; expr3)
    statement
```

Here `expr1` and `expr3` can also be a comma-separated list of expressions, which makes sense, e.g.,

```
for ($i = 0, $j = 1; $i < 3; $i++, $j++)
  echo $i, $j, PHP_EOL;
```

will output:

```
01
12
23
```

However, `expr2` is *also* allowed to be a list of expressions, and it is not completely clear why this should be possible. For instance,

```
for ($i = 0, $j = 1; $i < 3, $j < 2; $i++, $j++)
  echo $i, $j, PHP_EOL;
```

outputs only

```
01
```

Testing around a little bit, it seems that when `expr2` is a list of expressions, they are all evaluated, but only the return value of the last expression is used to decide whether to continue iterating.

Is there any realistic scenario where having a list of expressions as the loop's guard actually makes sense, i.e., is there any good reason that this is possible? Or is this more like an artefact of the language?

Comment: The whole syntax of this is directly derived from C. You can do it in C, therefore you can do it in PHP.

Answer (score 1):

I'm having a hard time thinking of a practical application for this but it does allow you to evaluate any expression before determining whether the loop has ended (a little like `do ... while`)

So, for instance:

```
function spaff($s) {
    echo "{$s}\n";
}
```

---

```
for($i=0; $i<10; $i++) {
    spaff($i);
}

//outputs
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

Because `$i` is evaluated to be less than 10 in the loop before the `spaff()` function is called, it is only called for values of `$i` less than 10.

---

However:

```
for($j=0; spaff($j), $j<10; $j++) {

}

//outputs
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

In this case `spaff($j)` is evaluated **before** `$j` is checked to be less than 10, so it is called for every value of `$j` including 10.

I suspect this is an *artefact of the language* - behavior inherited from C - but if anyone can think of a practical application for this behavior, I'd be interested to hear it.